# Cannot pass union type whose types resolve to different overloads

Tags: typescript

For reference, I am trying to resolve [DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped#29312](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/29312).

---

The following code results in an error but should not.

```js
declare const $: JQueryStatic;

let value: string | HTMLElement = {} as any;
$(value);
```

```
Argument of type 'string | HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PlainObject<any>'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'PlainObject<any>'.
```

The call signatures for `JQueryStatic` are currently defined as:

```js
interface JQueryStatic {
    <TElement extends HTMLElement = HTMLElement>(html: string, ownerDocument_attributes?: Document | JQuery.PlainObject): JQuery<TElement>;
    <TElement extends Element = HTMLElement>(selector: string, context?: Element | Document | JQuery): JQuery<TElement>;
    <T extends Element>(element: T): JQuery<T>;
    <T extends Element>(elementArray: T[]): JQuery<T>;
    <T>(selection: JQuery<T>): JQuery<T>;
    <TElement = HTMLElement>(callback: ((this: Document, $: JQueryStatic) => void)): JQuery<TElement>;
    <T extends JQuery.PlainObject>(object: T): JQuery<T>;
    <TElement = HTMLElement>(): JQuery<TElement>;
}

interface JQuery<T = HTMLElement> {
    jquery: string;
}

declare namespace JQuery {
    type PlainObject<T = any> = { [name: string]: T; };
}
```

`string` and `HTMLElement` have individual overloads that they could match to but not as a union. The solution in this scenario is to unify the signatures. I tried the following:

```js
interface JQueryStatic2 {
    // This solution doesn't entirely fulfill the original requirements but
    // seems like a good starting point.
    <TElement extends HTMLElement = never,
        JElement = never,
        T extends JQuery.PlainObject = never>(
        arg: string |
            TElement |
            TElement[] |
            JQuery<JElement> |
            ((this: Document, $: JQueryStatic) => void) |
            T
    ): JQuery<TElement | JElement | T>;
}
```

```
Argument of type 'string | HTMLElement' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | ((this: Document, $: JQueryStatic) => void) | JQuery<never> | never[]'.
  Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'string | ((this: Document, $: JQueryStatic) => void) | JQuery<never> | never[]'.
    Type 'HTMLElement' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
      Property 'length' is missing in type 'HTMLElement'.
```

I expect this to match with `TElement = HTMLElement`, `JElement = never`, and `T = never`. Instead, it looks like `TElement | T` get eliminated from the union.

I'm guessing this can be solved with conditional types but `@types/jquery` currently targets TypeScript 2.3 so I'd *prefer* a solution that doesn't use newer features to maintain compatibility.

Comment: I don't think you can do much better then `<TElement extends Element | JQuery.PlainObject>(arg: string | TElement[] | TElement  | JQuery<TElement>): JQuery<TElement>;` (and this has prblems with union of arrays and elements of different types `declare let mixed: HTMLImageElement | HTMLAnchorElement[];
let aArr5 = $$(mixed)` Conditional types would help... and 3.0 would probably make it seamless with spread (accepting the other arguments as well).

Comment: Note that you could use the [`typesVersions` feature](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#version-selection-with-typesversions) to target 3.1+ with newer types while leaving older versions alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resorted to using conditional types (requires TypeScript 2.8).

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    <TDeclared = JQuery._Unknown,
    T extends string | Element[] | JQuery<any> | Element | JQuery.PlainObject =
              string | Element[] | JQuery<any> | Element | JQuery.PlainObject,
    TReturn =
        TDeclared extends JQuery._Unknown ?
            T extends string ? HTMLElement :
            T extends Element[] | JQuery<any> ? T[number] :
            T extends Element | JQuery.PlainObject ? T :
            never :
        TDeclared>(html_selector_element_elementArray_object_selection: T): JQuery<TReturn>;
}

namespace JQuery {
    interface _Unknown {
        __unknown: never;
    }
}
```

This unifies a lot of the original signatures but drops the constraints on what is now `TDeclared`. `T` represents the argument's type and is constrained to the possible types of the original signatures. `TReturn` is equal to `TDeclared` if it is declared (i.e. not compatible with the sentinel type `JQuery._Unknown`), otherwise, it is inferred based on the type of `T`. Because of the way `T` is declared, the `never` branch should be unreachable.